# Unity3d: Setting light trails to active when reached a certain velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, effects, particles, rigid-bodies

I made a empty game object and then child the trails to the game object and then In the code:

```
if (movement.speed > minVelocity)
    {
        lightTrailHolder.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        lightTrailHolder.SetActive(false);
    }
```

But here comes the problem: the light trails get visible only the first time my vehicle exceeds the minimum and after that if my vehicle decreases and then again increases the speed, the light trails do not get active. This script is attached to my vehicles body and there I have attached a empty object containing the trails.

Desired Result: The light trails object should get active every time my vehicle exceeds the minVelocity.

Or is there a way in which I can make the trails disappear smoothly.

Hierarchy:

[image]

Script:

[image]

Comment: Is this code in a script attached to the `lightTrailHolder` game object?

Comment: This script is attached to my vehicles body and there I have attached a empty object containing the trails.

Comment: So `lightTrailHolder` has the reference to the child game object with the particle system component?

Comment: No , the lightTrailHolder is the parent of the light trails.

Comment: Now I'm confused, can you please post a screenshot showing the hierarchy and relationship of these game objects?

Comment: Done............

Comment: Good, so the code is in the `ParticleController` script component attached to the `Rover` game object, and `lightTrailHolder` has a reference to the `LightTrails` game object, correct? In this case it should work, you're not deactivating the game object that contains the script, the error must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now

As Galandil stated the problem was not in the code but was in the trail renderer. AutoDestruct was checked, I just had to uncheck it.

[image]